# How are linear and angular accelerations related to the inertial and centrifugal accelerations?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, acceleration, inertial-frames, centrifugal-force

I am studying robotics and I am studying how to send acceleration inputs to control a unicycle robot.

I have seen that I can send the unicycle linear and angular accelerations since they are the derivatives of linear and angular velocity.

But now, I would like to send different types of accelerations, such as inertial and centrifugal accelerations.

But the problem I have encountered is the fact that I don't have, unfortunately, much knowledge about these last two types of accelerations.

So, **can somebody please tell me if the linear and angular accelerations are somehow related to the inertial and centrifugal acceleration, and if yes, how are they related?**

To be clear on what I would like to do, I would like to use inertial and centrifugal acceleration instead of linear and angular acceleration. Is this possible?

The model of the unicycle with acceleration inputs , where the inputs are linear and angular accelerations is:

$\dot{x}=v\cos\theta$

$\dot{y}=v\sin\theta$

$\dot{\theta}=\omega$

$\dot{v}=a_{lin}$

$\dot{\omega}=a_{ang}$

and instead of $a_{lin}$ and $a_{ang}$ I would like to use inertial and centrifugal accelerations.

I have the quantities defined as follows:

$a_{in}=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta &-\sin\theta  &0 \\ 
\sin\theta &\cos\theta  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a_{lin}\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}+a_{ang}\begin{bmatrix}
-y\\ 
x\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

and

$a_{cen}=\omega^2\begin{bmatrix}
x &y  &0 
\end{bmatrix}^T$

where $a_{in}$ is the inertial acceleration and $a_{cen}$ is the centrifugal acceleration

Comment: Centrifugal acceleration is $-\omega \times (\omega \times r)$ but could you please define what is meant by inertial acceleration, and how it is different from linear acceleration?

Comment: I think I can simplify at most the context by saying this. I have a particle that is moving at constant velocity, so acceleration is zero, and there is an acceleration, so far linear and angular, that moves this particle. I hope it is clear, if not please tell me I will try to explain it better.

Comment: In this case, I have used a rotation matrix since I have anothe reference frame which rotates with respect to the world frame.

Comment: but as I am studying them now, I am starting to think that they cannot be used for control porpouses, since they are just apparent forces. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components of the acceleration are:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
   a_x \\
   a_y \\
   a_z \\
 \end{bmatrix}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} {\omega}^{2}x+\dot\omega \,y+2\,\omega\,{\dot y
}\\{\omega}^{2}y-\dot\omega \,x-2\,\omega\,{\dot x}
\\ 0\end {array} \right]$$

with :

$$\dot x=v\,\cos(\theta)~,\dot y=v\,\sin(\theta)$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
   a_x \\
   a_y \\
   a_z \\
 \end{bmatrix}= \left[ \begin {array}{c} {\omega}^{2}x+\dot\omega \,y+2\,\omega\,v\sin
 \left( \theta \right) \\ {\omega}^{2}y-\dot\omega \,x-
2\,\omega\,v\cos \left( \theta \right) \\ 0
\end {array} \right]$$

where $\omega=\dot{\theta}~,\dot\omega=\ddot{\theta}$

thus your inertial acceleration componets:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
   \ddot x \\
   \ddot y \\
    \ddot z\\
 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
   \dot{v}\,\cos(\theta)-v\,\dot\theta\sin(\theta) \\
    \dot{v}\,\sin(\theta)+v\,\dot\theta\cos(\theta) \\
  0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
   a_x \\
   a_y \\
   a_z \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$